How to change text of a div element with multiple classes?
I am a beginner programmer and I am creating a website using the Tutor LMS Pro plugin.
This plugin allows you to create a panel with courses, unfortunately it is not fully translated into my native language. I'm trying to translate individual headers using JavaScript, but for some reason it doesn't work.
I have previously translated another element that has the same class as the element I am currently trying to translate (tutor-mb-24).
Therefore, both elements are translated in the same way. I thought that if the second element shares the tutor-mb-24 class but also has other classes, the code will only work for it, but it doesn't work at all and is inferior to the code that only translates the tutor-mb-24 class for the other element.
I don't really understand the essence of the problem.
Element I'm working with:
<div class="tutor-col-12 tutor-col-md-8 tutor-col-lg-9">
  <div class="tutor-dashboard-content">
    <div class="tutor-fs-5 tutor-fw-medium tutor-color-black tutor-capitalize-text tutor-mb-24 tutor-dashboard-title"
       >
       Text I want to change
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

I tried:
document.getElementsByClassName("tutor-fs-5 tutor-fw-medium tutor-color-black tutor-capitalize-text tutor-mb-24 tutor-dashboard-title").textContent="New Text";

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var x1 = document.getElementsByClassName("tutor-fs-5 tutor-fw-medium tutor-color-black tutor-capitalize-text tutor-mb-24 tutor-dashboard-title");
    if (x1.length > 0) {
        x1[0].innerHTML = 'New Text';
    }

});


In the first 'I tried' code, you miss [0].

There are many ways to do this; add a unique ID => ( <div id="css-identifier"> ) attribute to the HTML if you have the ability. Then access it using it's uniqueId in Javascript using const uniqueID = document.getElementById('uniqueID'). This would be the easiest way if you have access to the HTML code and can add id selectors.
MDN: getElementById()
Selectors: querySelector() and querySelectorAll() and getElementsByClassName()
querySelector - gets the first occurrence of an element list. const uniqueID = querySelector('#uniqueID')
querySelectorAll gets a node list of each element - const classItems = document.querySelectorAll('.class-list-name') => returns a nodeList.
getElementsByClassName() returns an HTML list of elements - const classList = document.getElementsByClassName('class-list-name')  The later two lists that can be iterated over where
document.querySelector('.element') would give you the first occurrence of a list of elements.
If you need a different element with in the list of elements, you can loop over the elements and get the index of that element within the list of elements or array of elements.
You could create a helper function that does this for you and call it, passing the proper parameters needed for the code block within the method.
See further comments in the code snippet


const elements = document.getElementsByClassName('tutor-fs-5');
const secondElementString = "Some other text!"
const thirdElementString = "Change the third elements textContent!"

// helper function, pass in elements, index, string
function changeTextUsingIndex(els, index, str) {
  // basic for let loop that iterates over the elements 
  for (let i = 0; i <= els.length; i++) {
    // conditional if index of for loop strict comparision of index of parameter passed in
    if (i === index) {
      // change the text to passewd in string
      els[i].textContent = str;
    }
  }
}

// call your method and pass in params
// start at 0, second index would be 1 so we pass in 1 as the targeted index
changeTextUsingIndex(elements, 1, secondElementString);
changeTextUsingIndex(elements, 2, thirdElementString);
<div class="tutor-col-12 tutor-col-md-8 tutor-col-lg-9">
  <div class="tutor-dashboard-content">
    <div class="tutor-fs-5 tutor-fw-medium tutor-color-black tutor-capitalize-text tutor-mb-24 tutor-dashboard-title">
      Text with same class
    </div>
    <div class="tutor-fs-5 tutor-fw-medium tutor-color-black tutor-capitalize-text tutor-mb-24 tutor-dashboard-title">
      Text with same class
    </div>
    <div class="tutor-fs-5 tutor-fw-medium tutor-color-black tutor-capitalize-text tutor-mb-24 tutor-dashboard-title">
      Text with same class
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




And how does he use the ID? "I am a beginner programmer"

@PoulBak Well if he wanted to use an id, which is an attribute that can reference an element and should always be unique among the DOM, he would just add the attribute to the HTML he wants to target, example: <div id="uniqueId">. Then in JS or CSS reference that ID to target that specific element. const uniqueID = document.querySelector('#uniqueId') or document.getElementById('uniqueId') See MDN for more info ID Selectors getElementById()

You don't have tell me, I just thought you had to explain to a beginner.

use document.querySelector() method
with CSS syntax...


const div2change = document.querySelector('div.tutor-fs-5.tutor-fw-medium.tutor-color-black.tutor-capitalize-text.tutor-mb-24.tutor-dashboard-title');

div2change.textContent = 'new text';
<div class="tutor-col-12 tutor-col-md-8 tutor-col-lg-9">
  <div class="tutor-dashboard-content">
    <div class="tutor-fs-5 tutor-fw-medium tutor-color-black tutor-capitalize-text tutor-mb-24 tutor-dashboard-title"
       >
       Text I want to change
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



an other way :


const div2change = document.querySelector('div.tutor-dashboard-content > div');

div2change.textContent = 'new text';
<div class="tutor-col-12 tutor-col-md-8 tutor-col-lg-9">
  <div class="tutor-dashboard-content">
    <div class="tutor-fs-5 tutor-fw-medium tutor-color-black tutor-capitalize-text tutor-mb-24 tutor-dashboard-title"
       >
       Text I want to change
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




I find that using the div here 'div.tutor-d rest of the classes to be a bit of an "anti-pattern" for CSS as if they change to say a <tutortext from a div the script breaks when it would not have be the case here.  i.e. no need for the element name there perhaps as the OP did not use it.  Good use of const vs var here!
